# How do I change the per-period bars from charts.PerformanceSummary() to calendar year?

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I am trying to save a simple performance summary graph and was hoping there would be a way to change the periodicity of the bar charts from monthly returns to annual/ calendar year returns.

I've looked through the documentation for the package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/vignettes/PA-charts.pdf) but they didn't have any helpful information that I could find

```
  pdf(paste(Current, "Growth.pdf", sep = "_"))
  print(charts.PerformanceSummary(growth_returns,
                            colorset = colorsets,
                            wealth.index = TRUE,
                            main = paste(target_Ticker, "Investment Growth", sep = " ")))
```

Is what I currently have, but I can't find anything in the package to change this aspect. The returns are monthly as of now.

Comment: Not sure about that package, but you generally can't just change periodicity in the chart. You need to do so beforehand in the data frame by using `aggregate` or `dplyr::summarize`.

Comment: @hmhensen I had thought of that, but I would prefer to keep the Growth and Drawdown charts in monthly periodicity. I might have to just create the charts individually, if that is the case.